# Nim template where early binding is not possible?

Tags: nim-lang

There's the `build_type` template defined in the `lib.nim` library.

```
template build_type*[T](_: type[T]): T = T.build()
```

The object `B` uses that template to build object `A`.

And it doesn't work - because while `A` is visible in the `b.nim`, it is not visible in `main.nim`, where `B` is used.

It works if `A` imported into `main.nim` (see commented out import), but that feels wrong as it breaks encapsulation of the `B` internal details (as the code using `B` should also import `A` even if it doesn't use `A`).

I wonder if there's other way to make it work?

[playground](https://repl.it/@alexeypetrushin/template-dependency#main.nim)

```
# main.nim ------------------------------------------
import bobject #, aobject

echo B.build()

# bobject.nim ---------------------------------------
import lib, aobject

type B* = tuple[a: A]

proc build*(_: type[B]): B = (a: build_type(A))

# aobject.nim ---------------------------------------
type A* = tuple[v: int]

proc build*(_: type[A]): A = (0,)

# lib.nim -------------------------------------------
template build_type*[T](_: type[T]): T = T.build()
```

Compilation error:

```
/main.nim(3, 7) template/generic instantiation of `build` from here
/bobject.nim(5, 44) template/generic instantiation of `build_type` from here
/lib.nim(1, 43) Error: type mismatch: got <type A>
but expected one of: 
proc build(_: type[B]): B
  first type mismatch at position: 1
  required type for _: type B
  but expression 'T' is of type: type A

expression: build(T)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make it work changing `bobject.nim` to:

```
proc initB*(): B =
  (a: build_type(A))
```

And fixing `main.nim` to:

```
echo initB()
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Strange though, why it doesn't work with `proc build*(_: type[B]): B = (a: build_type(A))`